# How can I create a CHECK constraint on a VARCHAR column in SQL Server specifying a minimum data length?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, check-constraints

I have a `VARCHAR(30)` column in a Microsoft SQL Server database. I'd like to add a CHECK constraint that does not allow a value in the column to be less than 3 characters. What is the expression I must use?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

use:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[YOUR_TABLE]
ADD CONSTRAINT [MinLengthConstraint] CHECK (DATALENGTH([your_column]) > 2)
```

Reference:

- [DATALENGTH vs LEN](http://jane.dallaway.com/tsql-len-vs-datalength)
- [SQL SERVER – 2005 Constraint on VARCHAR(MAX) Field To Limit It Certain Length](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/01/sql-server-2005-constraint-on-varcharmax-field-to-limit-it-certain-length/)

Comment: Perfect, thanks for providing the note on DATALENGTH vs LEN as well.