# Minimum length constraint on a column

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I'm trying to implement a minimum length constraint in Oracle.

As I read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426005/how-can-i-create-a-check-constraint-on-a-varchar-column-in-sql-server-specifying) answer and multiple other similar questions I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table 
ADD CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE_PASSWORD_CK CHECK (DATALENGTH(password) >=4)
```

And I am getting `"DATALENGTH": invalid identifier"`. I also tried:

```
( DATALENGTH([password]) >=4 )
( LEN([password]) >=4 )
( LEN(password) >=4 )
```

What is the current format for this check constraint in Oracle?

Comment: Why are you using SQL Server functions in Oracle?

Comment: BTW: don't store passwords in clear in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database

Comment: @Mat, Thank you for the suggestion, Its only a test-purpose database

Comment: For purposes of reference, the 11.1 SQL Reference Manual's section on SQL Functions [can be found here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions001.htm#i88893). If you are using a different version of Oracle [you can find documentation for all versions here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/database.html). Best of luck.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`DATALENGTH()` returns the length in bytes in *SQL Server*.  The equivalent Oracle function is `LENGTHB()` (documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions076.htm)):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE_PASSWORD_CK CHECK (LENGTHB(password) >= 4)
```

However, for your purposes, I think the string length would be appropriate in both databases, `LENGTH()` in Oracle (or `LEN()` in SQL Server).